# Isometry group of Riemannian symmetric spaces and Lie groups

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras, symmetric-spaces

How do I prove the statement that for a Riemannian symmetric space $M$, the isometry group $Iso(M)$ is a Lie group? What can we say about the dimension of $Iso(M)$? And is its action transitive on $M$? And what can we say about the isometry group of a Lie group endowed with a left/right (not bi) invariant Riemannian metric (as we know if the metric is bi invariant, then the Lie group is a symmetric space)?

P.S  I not only look for answers but also for resource and literature to probe such related questions. (Note: In the definition of Riemannian symmetric space that I come across, the space is not assumed to be simply connected)

Comment: $Iso(M)$ is a Lie group is proved by [Myers and Steenrod](https://www​.jstor.org/stable/1968928).

Comment: @user10354138 The poster asked about symmetric spaces, on which the isometry group *does* always act transitively.

Comment: Try Helgasson's book and see if you can handle it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What about isometry groups of lie groups with left invariant (not bi invariant) metric?